# Javascript adding and removing values from an array which are called outside the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am adding a bunch of spans to a div layer with appendchild like so:

```
var newSent = document.createElement("SPAN");
var current = document.createTextNode(sentInput.value);
newSent.style.backgroundColor = sentColor;
newSent.className = "sentSpan";
newSent.id = count - 1;
newSent.appendChild(current);
outputBox.appendChild(newSent);
```

Where outputBox is the name of the div layer and sentInput is the current value of an input text box. I need each of these spans to be click-able, and then delete their value from an array. Currently I have an event listener for this:

```
delCount = 0;
newSent.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var x = parseInt(newSent.id);

    sentCount.splice(x - delCount, 1);
    sentNum.splice(x - delCount, 1);

    delCount = delCount + 1;

    newSent.remove(x);
});
```

The idea is that every time I delete a span, the delCount goes up to compensate for the now smaller array.

This doesn't work very well after a couple of deletions... I don't seem to be able to figure out the math or the proper method for handling the changing array. After clicking two or three spans I end up deleting the value in the array that was associated with the span next to it, but successfully removing the span itself. This array is displayed on a graph, so it's vital that it's displayed properly.

I temporarily had the arrays replace the deleted values with "0" which worked very well, but I need them to not show up in the array at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eL11o6mu/ though the display looks terrible in a window that small...

Comment: will you be able to create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please prepare jsfiddle for that code, otherwise It might fall into darkness..

Comment: The problem is since you are deleting it based on index, when an item is deleted the location of elements after it will be moved by 1 index down but the delete code will still refer to the old index... so if you can create a demo we can explain it better...

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added a jsfiddle at the bottom if you want to look...